# Ways std::getline(std::cin, string) can fail from keyboard input

Tags: c++, cin, getline

I am writing this function to ask for a particular input type. is_type just validates that the string recieved can be casted using stringstream to the desired type.

```
template<typename T>
T get_type(std::string prompt)
{
    T output;
    std::cout << prompt;
    std::string Input;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, Input) && !is_type<T>(Input))
    {
            std::cout << "Invalid input type. Please try again:\n"
              << prompt;
    }

    std::stringstream(Input) >> output;
       return output;
}
```

The functions seems to work as desired except when I type ctrl + Z for example.
What is the appropriate way to deal with this?

I added:

```
template<typename T>
    T get_type(std::string prompt)
    {
        T output;
        std::cout << prompt;
        std::string Input;
        while (std::getline(std::cin, Input) && !is_type<T>(Input))
        {
                std::cout << "Invalid input type. Please try again:\n"
              << prompt;
        }
        if (!std::cin)
        {
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        output = get_type<std::string>(prompt) ;
        return output;
        }
        std::stringstream(Input) >> output;
           return output;
    }
```

Which asks again for input after for example ctrl+Z
Does that solve my problem of std::getline(std::cin, std::string) failing under kewyboard input from the user?

Also, why do I have to hit enter 2 times for the

```
output = get_type<std::string>(prompt) ;
```

line to run inside the if.

Comment: Your function returns a value. If it can't read a line from stdin, and can't return a meaningful default value, I think the only appropriate thing to do is raise an exception.

Comment: Also, your `is_type` seems redundant, since you can simply check the result of `stringstream::operator>>` inside the loop, instead of after the loop ends

Comment: if it can't get a value (because input is eof) I managed to keep asking using the second code. But is that safe? In what other ways can keyboard input fail under getline(cin, string)

Comment: What does your initial code **do** on ^Z that you don’t want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::getline` could  fail if you've used `stdin` previously without clearing the failbit and if the input exceeds `std::string::max_size` (see comment of Davis Herring).
Otherwise, I know of no way to let `std::getline` fail except by EOF (`^Z/^D`).

But, here is your code with some small improvements:

```cpp
template<typename T>
T get_type(std::string prompt)
{
    T output;
    std::string input;
    while(true)
    {
        std::cout << prompt;
        std::getline(std::cin, input);
        std::istringstream iss(input);
        if(!std::cin)
        {
            std::cin.clear();
        //  std::clearerr(stdin);
        }
        else if(iss >> output && iss.eof())
            return output;

        std::cout << "Invalid input type. Please try again:\n";
    }
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, it is necessary to use `clearerr` on `stdin` on some systems. If your system requires that, just uncomment `std::clearerr(stdin);`.

Because of your 2x `<Enter>` problem: the ignore statement is unnecessary. You just ignore the next input (that's why you have to hit `<Enter>` twice).

Comment: You certainly can `clear` and keep reading past EOF on Unix on a terminal or a regular file (though not on a pipe or socket).  (But `^Z` is *suspend* on Unix and EOF on Windows.)  And the conversion to `bool` checks *all* the error flags.

Comment: I just wanted to add that `std::strinstream(input) >> output;` is not enough, as `13ab` would pass as `13`  etc. Could you expand on what other ways can `std::getline(std::cin,string)` fail under keyboard input?

Comment: @DavisHerring I thought the same way, but when I tested it, I was unable to reuse `std::cin`. `std::cin.clear()` did unset the eofbit, but when calling std::getline, the eofbit was again set immediately. You are right about the conversion, I'll change my answer.
@DanielDuque You are right, I have to check the eofbit of the istringstream. Actually, I don't know of any other way except `^D/^Z` to let it fail.

Comment: @Unterfliege: On some implementations, you apparently **also** need to use `clearerr` on the underlying `FILE*`; I consider that a bug.

Comment: @DavisHerring thank you for the corrections, I edited my answer. You are right, I had to use `clearerr` in order to reuse `stdin`. Now it should be correct.

Comment: One more technicality: `getline` fails if it overruns the maximum `string` length.  Exceedingly rare on most modern systems, but it is possible to distinguish as it sets *only* `failbit`.